# Python - Sorting huge array into multiples

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working with a map of which is split up into 750 x 750 numbered tiles. These are stored in a JSON file. My aim is to pull the data and split each tile into separate arrays / chunks.

I already have it working, but I'm a python beginner and the code is really slow (it is handling 500,000+ numbers). Wondered if there was any faster method available for doing the same thing.

First I pull the json data into an array

```
with open("data.json") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    arr = data["mapLayer"][0]["tiles"]
```

Then I run through the array and sort them into separate `chunk` arrays based on their position:

```
x=0
y=0 

for tile in arr:
    chunkPos = str(x/16) + "x" + str(y/16)
    chunks[chunkPos].append(tile)
    x += 1

    // reset x pos when it reaches map edge
    if x == 750
        x=0
        y=y+1
```

Comment: This might not be too helpful to hear, but you should really consider whether the object *needs* to be stored as it is... There are usually much faster, and more powerful modules to use when dealing with large amounts of data (such as Numpy, Pandas). They are considerably faster because the operations (+looping) are precisely written in C, rather than Python.

Comment: What does your file look like? It's hard to guess where the script bogs down, but you might be blowing out your memory since `json.load` needs to read in the entire file into memory. If the structure is simple, you could reduce your memory footprint by reading it (ad hoc) line by line.

Comment: Second, how is `chunks` defined? You use `append` on the dict elements, but it looks like each will be an array containing just one value of `tile`. There might be something you can simplify here too. (But I wouldn't expect it to make much difference in performance.)

Answer (score 0):

you can store your tiles in numpy array and than just reshape your array using 4 dimensions
(i assume that 256 is your chunk size)

```
import numpy as np

 with open("data.json") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    arr = np.array(data["mapLayer"][0]["tiles"])


arr = np.reshape(arr, (750, 1,750, 256))
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this later, not able to test at the mo